# Ubuntu 20.04 - Boot Problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, reboot, boot-repair

I was a Windows user for a long time. But i found Ubuntu 20.04 more good. So, i switched to it ( Dual Boot) . The only problem with Ubuntu is boot problems. I frequently end up stuck on the boot screen.
I updated my kernel and ubuntu stopped working. It get stuck on reboot.

Sometimes, i type in terminal sudo reboot to reboot my pc.
The logo of ubuntu comes. After few seconds black screen come and then again ubuntu screen come. Then a forever black screen come.
After, this i changed some Grub file settings ( of splash screen) it worked. But then my Nvidia X server settings became empty. Then i switched to newer Nvidia driver. Then black screen came.

I don't know, i fix a bug to get another bug in Ubuntu. Sometimes, i just reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Is Secure Boot in BIOS disabled? It can make trouble to Nvidia drivers. And what are "some" grub settings?

Comment: Secure boot is enabled and i think if i disable it. I will loose my ubuntu 20.04. And some grub settings are disabling splash screen

Comment: Why do you think you'll "lose your ubuntu"?

Comment: no care about ubuntu , i just reinstall it on the same partition when it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I've used Ubuntu for the last 10 years at least without a single Boot issue until 19 Disco Dingo and 20 Focal Fossa. I bought a Linux ready Thinkpad when I startd having problems but the hardware seems unlikely if it's Linux ready. My guess is that there is a push to change the installer so it may be a deliberate accident. I'm going back to 18. Think I got it on a start up disk somewhere.